# loading a FastText model in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, gensim, fasttext, language-model

I have trained a FastText model in Python and saved the files into a folder. These are the contents of the folder:

```
fasttext.model
fasttext.model.trainables.syn1neg.npy
fasttext.model.trainables.vectors_ngrams_lockf.npy
fasttext.model.trainables.vectors_vocab_lockf.npy
fasttext.model.wv.vectors.npy
fasttext.model.wv.vectors_ngrams.npy
fasttext.model.wv.vectors_vocab.npy
```

How can I load the model in MATLAB and extract the word embeddings of certain words?
This is what we do in Python:

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText
model = FastText.load(fasttext.model)
vector = model.wv[word]
```

Is there a similar thing in MATLAB? How can I get the word embeddings generated by a FastText model in Python in MATLAB and work with them?

Comment: Please read this: https://it.mathworks.com/help/textanalytics/ref/fasttextwordembedding.html

Comment: That is for loading the pretrained FastText model. I want to load the model I have trained by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **trainWordEmbedding** and **readWordEmbedding** function

Train and test your word embedding: "emb"
Word embedding doesn't need bag of words. It just needs tokenized document ("cleanDoc").

```
emb = trainWordEmbedding(cleanDoc, "Dimension",100)
writeWordEmbedding(emb,"medEmb.vec");
```

List down the vocabulary in the embedding:
emb.Vocabulary